# notifyjs disappears without hide effect

Tags: jquery, notifyjs

I have a notification with notifyjs jQuery plugin.

```
var notifyProps = {};
notifyProps.showAnimation = 'slideDown';
notifyProps.showDuration = 2500;
notifyProps.hideAnimation = 'slideUp';
notifyProps.hideDuration = 2500;
notifyProps.style = 'myStyle';
notifyProps.clickToHide = true;
var insertId = ("myId"+ Math.random()).replace('0\.',''); //just an id
$.notify({title: $('<div id="'+insertId+'"></div>').append(elem.element)},notifyProps);
```

The notification appears correctly with the showAnimation of slideDown, but when clicked, it just disappears instead of sliding up, or fading out if `fadeOut` is set as `hideAnimation`.

I'm using addStyle to define `myStyle` like so:

```
$notify.addStyle("myStyle", {
  html:
 "<div>" +
      "<div class='clearfix'>" +
          "<div class='lb-close'></div>" +
          "<div class='notify-title' data-notify-html='title'/>" +
      "</div>" +
"</div>",
css: "-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);"
});
```

debugging this, the `show()` method of Notification is being called with `false` as a parameter, but when it reaches the final line of this function:

```
return elems[fn].apply(elems, args);
```

The notification div just disappears at once instead of transitioning out. What else can I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of these lines, in `Notification.prototype.show` :

```
callback = function() {
  if (!show && !_this.elem) {
    _this.destroy();
  }
  if (userCallback) {
    return userCallback();
  }
};
```

For some reason, `_this.elem` is always undefined, which I guess in turn destroys the notification element. I just comment that check out of the callback, and everything seems OK.